# How to improve the speed of groupby/transform?

Tags: pandas

I want to implement the `groupmax` function, which finds the max value within each group, and assign it back to the rows within each group. It seems `groupby(name).transform(max)` is what I need. E.g.

```
In [1]: print df
  name     value
0    0  0.363030
1    0  0.324828
2    0  0.499279
3    1  0.799836
4    1  0.886653
5    1  0.335056

In [2]: print df.groupby('name').transform(max)
      value
0  0.499279
1  0.499279
2  0.499279
3  0.886653
4  0.886653
5  0.886653
```

However this approach is very slow when the size of the data frame becomes large and there are many small groups. E.g. the following code will hang there forever

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : repeat([str(x) for x in range(0, 1000000)], 2), 'value' : rand(2000000)})
print df.groupby('name').transform(max)
```

I wonder if there is any fast solutions for this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: this is implemented in master/0.14.1 (coming soon), see here; https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6496; you can implemented pretty easily by following the included recipe

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': np.repeat(list(map(str,range(10**6))), 2), 'value': np.random.rand(2*10**6)})
>>> %timeit df.groupby("name").max().loc[df.name.values].reset_index(drop=True)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.12 s per loop
```

Still not great, but better.

Comment: Thanks! It's a huge improvement on speed.